Simpsons episode where Homer is told to not feel bad
Homer was at someone's house partying. He said he feels bad because he ditched his family at home. Someone comes along and says to Homer that he should stop feeling bad. Immediately, Homer goes OK and starts enjoying the party. 
There were a lot of people at the party. I think after homer partied, he drove home drunk, and ended up driving over his front lawn and slept on the kitchen table, where Marge found him in the morning. I think this happened in the same episode, but I'm not certain.
What episode/clip was that?

Seems like Homer would do this kind of thing a lot... Do you remember anything else?

There were a lot of people at the party. I think after homer partied, he drove home drunk, and ended up driving over his front lawn and slept on the kitchen table, where Marge found him in the morning. I think this happened in the same episode, but I'm not certain.

Are you sure it's a party or its moe's bar

I don't think it was The Simpsons... I think you're remembering Family Guy's pilot episode.

Peter asks Lois for permission to attend an upcoming stag party. After he promises he won't drink, Lois lets him go. Unfortunately, Peter forgets his promise to Lois and plays such drinking games as "Drink the beer".

In that party, this dialogue occurs:

Peter: Y'know, I feel kinda bad, you guys. I promised my wife I wouldn't drink. 
Quagmire: Aw, don't feel bad, Peter. 
Peter: Ah, gee, I've never thought of it like that!

Peter comes home drunk and sleeps on the kitchen table. He then loses his job for being hung over. Here are some more clips from the episode, maybe they'll jog your memory:




Of course, there's always the possibility that Family Guy lifted the plot and dialogue wholesale from The Simpsons... Definitely won't be the last time they'll do that. :P

I instantly remembered this part of Family Guy.

I know your memory is vague about what episode but try this ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mansion_Family
